# regarding xrdb: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, remote-desktop

after `ssh` to a machine, I got the following message,

```
xrdb: Resource temporarily unavailable
xrdb: Can't open display 'localhost:10.0'
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Add `strace -o xrdb.strace` in front of the `xrdb` call and post the resulting trace file.

Comment: `xrdb` is trying to connect the X server at `localhost:10.0`, and gets an error. Does you `ssh` do X forwarding? If yes, it likely tries to contact the X server of the machine you are ssh-ing from.  Which machine would that be, and what X server does it run?

Comment: bump. Same issue. Using SUSE Enterprise. Trying to get help on Stackexchange because priority support is not working :s..